# Python Pandas create multiple dataframe with cicle for

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a way to create a multiple dataframe in Pandas with a cicle for?
I post a piece of code to make you understand what I mean.

```
tickers = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT']
for t in tickers:


klines = client.get_historical_klines(t, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE, "100 minutes ago UTC")


data = pd.DataFrame(klines).reset_index()


data.columns = ['0', 'Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Close time', 'Quote asset volume', 'Number of trades', 'Taker buy base', 'Taker buy quote', '1']


data.set_index('Date')


data = data.drop(['Quote asset volume', 'Number of trades', 'Taker buy base', 'Taker buy quote', '0', '1'], axis=1)


data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], unit='ms')


data['Close time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Close time'], unit='ms')
```

When I call 'data' to visualize the two dataframes, I can see only the last one.
How can I see both dataframes at same time?

Comment: the last iteration overwrites the previous one as per the code above, what is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

At the *bottom-of-the-loop* put the objects in a container like a list.

```
tickers = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT']
stuff = []
for t in tickers:
    ...
    data = pd.DataFrame(klines).reset_index()
    ...
    stuff.append[data]
```

Or a dict if you want to associate them with something.

```
tickers = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT']
stuff = {}
for t in tickers:
    ...
    data = pd.DataFrame(klines).reset_index()
    ...
    stuff[t] = data
```

Comment: Yes it's working with the dictionary. Thanks